# HTML5 custom attribute updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i get the value of an `html5` attribute using jQuery ?

```
<button data-direction="next" data-next="2"></button>
```

I want to be able to get the newest set value of `data-next`.

When i change the value dynamically using javascript and then try to get it using
`$('[data-direction="next"][data-next]').data('next')`,
it always returns the data as set when loading the page not after being updated - in this case `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('[data-direction="next"][data-next]').attr('data-next')` should work..

Comment: +1 `data-next` is not a true html5 data notation, but simply an html attribute.

Comment: You access them like any other attribute – using [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). You also can't access most HTML-values by their name.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with @Pierre. Use the attr() method to retrieve the desired value.

A point to note, your selector could turn out to be slower. Check this [article](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck) out.